# K6 Use POST to login in

Tags: javascript, k6

Ive been working with K6 recently and need to test my API, the login function needs a json in order to get the data but it does not get called on the run, heres my code for the script

```js
import http from 'k6/http';
import { sleep } from 'k6';

export default function () {
  let strGlobalUrl = '192.168.0.1';
  let url = 'http://'+strGlobalUrl+'/api/CompanyLogin';
  let data = JSON.stringify({
    strEmail : 'email',
    strPassword : 'password',
    boolLoginPage : true 
  });

  let params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'dataType': 'json'
    }
  };

  let res = http.post(url, data, params);
  console.log(res.intResponse);
}
```

It should call the function and get print 200 on the console log, theres something I do wrong or is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from my boss, I forgot to include ':5050' in the value of strGlobalUrl due Im testing in my local copy of the server

I hope this would help someone else

Comment: I don't think "use the right IP and port when communicating with a web service" will help any future visitor. That's one of the first things to check: am I talking to the correct server and am I talking to the server at all.